# ValidationMessageFor for different object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using mvc4, in my view I have a declaration

```
        @model IEnumerable<UserDisplay>
```

on the **same** view I want to have a Form with "create" post for different object type name "Review"

how can I use the EditorFor and `ValidationMessageFor` ? cause model is of different type.

this is not working

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Review</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Info) 
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Info)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Info)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FromId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FromId)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FromId)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ToId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ToId)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ToId)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a partial view for that form that uses the @model declaration of the required type then use `@Html.Partial("mySubFormView")`. Don't mix model types in your views, it makes life too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a view model containing both objects.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<UserDisplay> { get; set; }
    public Review Review { get; set; }
}
```

Then your model declaration in the view becomes:

```
@model TheNamespace.For.MyViewModel
```

Which will allow you to use `@Html.EditorFor` and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` helpers.